# Twitter4j - Getting tweets of a particular user in a time interval

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to get the tweets of an user in a time interval, for example a user's tweets between a 6 months period. I can get all the tweets of a user with **getUserTimeline** functionality but it seems like it doesn't give me any option about any date interval.

I need something like **since** and **until** parameters which is provided by **Query** class of Twitter4j. I would use that class but it only support searching for keywords. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe twitter itself provides any date/time related options for getting tweets (aka [user timeline statuses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)).

If you can extract the tweet ID for the last tweet in that 6 month window, you can set that as max_id and then iterate backwards by setting the lowest tweet ID as max_id till you hit the start of the 6 month window.

Answer (score 0):

The current version does not have any provision to get the tweets between a specific time interval using date and time with `getUserTimeline` functionality.

It can be done using `since_id` and `max_id` only AFAIK.

[User TimeLine](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

[Search tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)